# How can I create a function in google sheets that manipulates a new array that it creates dependent on the variables already existing in the row?

Tags: javascript, google-sheets, google-apps-script

I'm trying to determine the average of an array made from values within my google sheet form, but whether or not said values are in the array is dependent on if whether or not there are values in each column for the active row. The average is also equal to the length of the array PLUS the value of another variable dependent on the active row, so it's not just a straight average. I'm relatively new to both JavaScript and working with Google Sheets, and I'm having some trouble understanding how to manipulate it correctly, so I would really appreciate any help.

[image: code I have so far]

seems to run, but returns #NAME?

Update: New code, but it looks like it runs for too long and times out? I don't see an infinite loop, so I'm not sure how to fix it. I am having fun figuring it out though!

```js
function myFunction() {
  const s = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  const currentCell = s.getActiveCell();
  const row = currentCell.getRow();
  const rowRange = s.getRange('A' + row + ":GV" + row);
  const columnRange = s.getRange('A1:GV1');
  let k = 0;
  let columnList = []
  while (k < columnRange.length) {
    columnList.push(columnRange[k]);
    k++;
  }
  let newArr = [];
  let i = 0
  let currentColumn = columnList[i];
  while (currentColumn !== 'GW') {
    let referenceCell = currentColumn + row;
    if (referenceCell === true) {
      newArr.push(currentColumn + '203');
    }
  }
  let sum;
  let j = 0;
  while (j < newArr.length) {
    sum += newArr[j];
  }
  let morEnergy = 'GZ' + row;
  let denominator = newArr.length + morEnergy;
  return sum / denominator;
}
```

Update: I thought maybe it wouldn't work without a reference sheet, so I tried implementing it on my actual sheet, and it says Error: Exceeded maximum execution time (line 0). So I have no idea how to fix that. But I still feel like this is progress!

Comment: `for (column < GW)` doesn't look like a valid for loop.

Comment: Oh! Thank you! I changed it to a while loop and that got rid of the syntax error. Thank you for your help!

Comment: Don't use images of text. They're hard to copy/paste/search/test.

Comment: Thank you! That makes sense, I'll fix it